# NFS mounts fails on reboot

Tags: nfs

I setup NFS mounting shares on a Ubuntu server 16.04 from a Synology NAS.
The NAS is the NFS server and the Ubuntu server is the NFS client.
I edited the /etc/fstab on the Ubuntu server as such:

```
## NFS mounting

171.65.68.203:/volume1/BALDAR   /nfs/baldar nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

Each time i reboot the Ubuntu server, the NFS fails to mount the share. I have to manually mount the share.
Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Eric

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i usually dont include the // in the fstab. I have other servers wiht NFS setup but this server is only one giving me trouble.

Comment: That would be my bad.  I was thinking CIFS mounts that I use between hosts since I have a mixed network.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

After two and a half years I can't believe that nobody has answered this. No doubt the OP has resolved the issue but in case anyone else stumbles on this, here is what works in the /etc/fstab on my systems with a Synology DS216J:

```
# Synology NFS mount
192.168.0.100:/volume1/Public /media/username/NAS nfs soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,vers=3
```

This works equally on Ubuntu 16.04, Mint 19 Tara and Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 LTS clients.

Comment: Thank you @Scooby-2. I never lost hope :)